# How to add length of 2 lists which has dictionaries it it in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have two lists, both the lists are having number of dictionaries. eg.:
`list_one = [{"key1": "value"}, {"key1": "value"}]`
`list_two = [{"key2": "value"}, {"key2": "value"}]`

I want to add length of these two lists in django template tag, so the output will be 4 in this case.

I have tried with below but couldn't make it.

```
{{ list_one|length|add:list_2|length }}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`{% with … %} … {% endwith %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) to calculate the length of the second list:

```
{% with len2=list_two|length %}
    {{ list_one|length|add:len2 }}
{% endwith %}
```